# Xamarin Form - Add png icon in toolbar with color

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my code

```
ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("User", "userAvatar.png", async () => {
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }));
```

It's not working. It's place a masked single color image instead a png in colors.

I'm trying to archive something like this...

[image]

Any clue ?

Comment: This isn't possible from Xamarin.Forms directly. You will need to use a custom renderer

Answer (score 1):

I was going mad about this issue once, too (my situation was a bit more subtle, I had a plain and a colored verion of the icon and was wondering **why the heck** the colored icon would not be loaded) and unfortunately it's not that easy to overcome.

The icons being monochrome is the default behavior for iOS apps and Xamarin.Forms implements this behavior. According to [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/123505/#Comment_123505) you'll need a custom renderer to show colored icons in the navigation bar.

**Edit**

According to [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/74195/#Comment_74195), you'll have to set the `UIImageRenderingMode` for the respective images in your custom renderer

```
image = image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
```

using the renderer implementation from [this answer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/101970/#Comment_101970), it should be something in the line of

```
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyProject.iOS.Renderers.IosMainMenuRenderer))]

namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers {
    public class IosMainMenuRenderer : TabbedRenderer {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
            var items = TabBar.Items;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
                items[i].Image = items[i].ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
                items[i].SelectedImage = items[i].SelectedImage.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I have not tested this!

Answer (score 1):

For a color logo on the right on all my navigation pages I used this custom renderer:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomNavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]

namespace App.iOS
{
    public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
            var logo = NavigationBar.TopItem.RightBarButtonItem.Image;
            if (logo == null) return;

            if (logo.RenderingMode == UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
            {
                return;
            }

            NavigationBar.TopItem.RightBarButtonItem.Image = logo.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not use a toolbar, instead, set the type of this page as a *Modal* when navigating to it(Using Navigation.PushModal()). And add a horizontal LinearLayout that will act as the toolbar.